# JQuery: Link effect on mouseover

Tags: jquery, hover

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#menu a").mouseover(function(){
        $(this).animate({top: +5}, function(){
            $(this).animate({top: -5});
        });
    });
});
```

I want the links in my menu to jump up and down (one time) when the moused is placed over them. 
The problem with this code is that if I keep the mouse over the link it will keep moving up and not coming back down, so I think maybe I should remove this event at the beginning of the function and replace it back when it's over. I really dont know whats the best approach for this...

Answer (score 1):

You may try using #wooble function

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [mouseenter](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) instead of mouseover?

Comment: Yes I have. Happens the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Check how you have positioned your links. Your code is working for me if I set position as relative for the links. Here is the JSFiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/Nbm6K/